# Assign MPMediaItemArtwork to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaitem

I have a table view, where i display my songs via MPMedia. What i want is, that the album cover for each song gets displayed in the cell, too. I tried it the same way i did with song and artist:

`cell?.textLabel?.text = items.title
 cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = items.artist
 cell?.imageView?.image = items.artwork`

but I get the error "Cannot assign value of type MPMediaItemArtwork? to type UIImage?"

Anyone know how to do this? If you need more code just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Found out, the answer is `item.artwork.imageWithSize`